# variable value becomes destroyed with clearInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to change the text of an `<p>` element every 100ms. Every 100ms the number becomes `n + 1`. This loop only gets executed when the user clicks the screen. If the user stops that the loop become stopped.

Now the problem is that the current value of the variable `scoren` always starts with `0`. That's not how a score works. How can I edit the code that `scoren` only starts at page load with `0` and resumes after the second `mousedown` with the current value? Also how can I save the `scoren` value after `mouseup` and resumes with the value?

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a0sg10nt/) for that.

```
<p id="score">score:</p>
```

```js
var loop;

function game() {
    var scoren = 0;
    score = setInterval(function() {
        scoren += 1;
        $('#score').text('score:' + scoren);
    }, 100);
}   

$(document).mousedown(function() {
    game();
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(score);
});
```

Comment: make your variable `scoren` global, don't put it inside the function `game()`. When it's inside the function, it'll always start at 0. When you make it global (e.g. putting it outside the function) you'll start with the value that it stored in that variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to learn first how scopes works in javascript. You are reinitializing on every mousedown the scoren variable. Make this:

```
var loop;
var scoren = 0;
function game() {
  score = setInterval(function() {
    scoren += 1;
    $('#score').text('score:' + scoren);
  },100);

}   

$(document).mousedown(function() {
  game();
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
  clearInterval(score);
});
```

Comment: All right! Scopes problems are very common here in S.O. ;) We just answer automatically

Answer (score 2):

You need to take your `var scoren = 0;` line outside your function.

```
var loop;
var scoren = 0; //This line is important
function game() {

score = setInterval(function() {
    scoren += 1;
     $('#score').text('score:' + scoren);
},100);



}   
    $(document).mousedown(function() {
    game();
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
clearInterval(score);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

```js
var scoren = 0;

/* cache object to improve performance */
var scoreBoard = $('#score');

function game() {
  score = setInterval(function() {
    scoreBoard.text(++scoren);
  }, 100);
}   

$(document).mousedown(function() {
  game();
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
  clearInterval(score);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>score:<span id="score"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you could do it. You could create an object that is reusable:

```js
var loop;
var game = new Game();
function Game() {
    this.scoren = 0;
    this.score = null;
    this.start = function () {
    this.score = setInterval(function(currentGame) {
         currentGame.scoren += 1;
         $('#score').text('score:' + currentGame.scoren);
     }.bind(null, this), 100);
    }
    this.stop = function () {
     clearInterval(this.score);
  }
}

$(document).mousedown(function() {
    game.start()
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
    game.stop();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="score">score:</p>
```

Instead of creating a new `Game()` every time someone clicks you can re-use the same `Game()` object...